# .aspx page fails to open while recording with JMeter on IE11

Tags: https, jmeter, internet-explorer-11

I am new to JMeter and is currently experiencing the following problem:

I am recording a test with an HTTPS url.

I start JMeter and the CA dialog is displayed. 
I install the certificate and continue to launch the site I am testing, example `https://....../genisys/login.aspx` - the log in page loads 
I enter the domain, username, and password then click the log in button. 
The site loads the default.aspx page which displays the menu. 
I click on the menu to access a capture page and the Server Error page is displayed with the following information:

```
Server Error in '/GeniSys' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Invalid character in a Base-64 string. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
Exception Details: System.FormatException: Invalid character in a Base-64 string.
Source Error: 
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  
Stack Trace: 
[FormatException: Invalid character in a Base-64 string.]
   System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s) +0
   QueryStringModule.Decrypt(String inputText) in c:\G_3.7.10.10\Genisys.Website\App_Code\QueryStringModule.cs:122
   QueryStringModule.context_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\G_3.7.10.10\Genisys.Website\App_Code\QueryStringModule.cs:46
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +68
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5485; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5483**
```

The URL displayed after clicking on the PolicyCapture menu option is as follows:

```
GeniSys/Policy/PolicyCapture.aspx?qustr=jdeaURtP7Y+xja0gydkHMSiFcwnCFAZVO7CoQe4mJPcQXF49MdPDlyzkttMmQcmi55Rg4GEEODHn09+H3S1rgtO+zf5T8azvVHxi8LGBTS+k0APJvNeJfA+fbT6s2PRmrm0HIJ6aXeA3fE6FEXV7EQ==
```

I have disabled the proxy recording and tried to access the page using IE11 and the same result is displayed, but the 'qustr' string is different.

The View Results Tree listener displays the following information:

```
Thread Name: 
Sample Start: 2015-05-29 12:03:24 CAT
Load time: 1628
Connect Time: 241
Latency: 1628
Size in bytes: 4183
Headers size in bytes: 240
Body size in bytes: 3943
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Response code: 500
Response message: Internal Server Error
Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 3943
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 29 May 2015 10:03:26 GMT
HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: text/html; charset=utf-8
DataEncoding: utf-8***

The Request shows this:
GET https://<host details here>/GeniSys/Policy/PolicyCapture.aspx?qustr=jdeaURtP7Y+xja0gydkHMfhqaS6Tm5sLTGg98d%2FgvpF4CzUI9FWYWJ7VBVfmeuccWFSnJVXUikDIOG0SGbVKYg182Gt4munLrlMJ5afB3FvgwlifUQJbU%2F5SGvxu9TE%2F5Zu8LxWqqSRJwjiWf9Pfaw%3D%3D

[no cookies]

Request Headers:
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: https://<host detail here>/GeniSys/default.aspx
Accept-Language: en-ZA
DNT: 1
Pragma: no-cache
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0E)
Accept: application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/x-shockwave-flash, */*
Host: <host details here>
```

I notice that the 'qustr' from the website URL is different from the Request on JMeter: 282 /GeniSys/Policy/PolicyCapture.aspx; the JMeter Request has the string URL encoded. Maybe that is the issue at had, but I am not sure.

Will whomever is reading this, and has the suggestions or solutions, please help me solve this issue? I will greatly appreciate your efforts.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: the 'qustr' value sounds like it would stand for query string, looks like a base64 encoded string and possibly changes every single time you login and click that button. You'll obviously get an error if you use a string from an older recording.  You will have to determine how to capture or generate the correct string for the test session. Another difference between the two strings is, one of them is HTML encoded which means `=` in the end is represented as `%3D`

Comment: Thanks RaGe - I have not replayed the recorded script. The Server Error message is displayed while I am recording the script and when I click on the Menu > Policy > PolicyCapture option. Yes, the query string is different each time the menu option is clicked, but how do I work around or fix the Server Error  message. I am not able to continue recording my business process because of that error message.

Comment: Ah, So apparently your issue is that Jmeter proxy is automatically changing the `=` in the url to `%3D` and the server does not know what to do with it. I wonder if there is a way to disable url encoding in Jmeter proxy settings. This may not be in your control, but - your server should decode html encoded strings in the url, not handling that correctly would seem like a bad practice.

Comment: As a workaround you can try using the [Blazemeter Chrome plugin](http://blazemeter.com/blog/recording-https-traffic-jmeters-proxy-server) to record your script. It generally handles this sort of thing better than Jmeter proxy.